# Pipe output of command in Shell, how to redirect without save it between in an file?

Tags: shell, pipe

do someone know how to make this in one line of code. 
I mean by that without save the output of the ls in temp.txt between

```
ls | cat $x > temp.txt
while read line; do echo foo/$line; done < temp.txt
```

Comment: What is `$x` there?

Comment: the piped output of ls

Answer (score 1):

Use printf with a glob.

```
printf 'foo/%s\n' *
```